# Automatically pass unparsed arguments to JavaExec-type task in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to pass a lot of arguments to a JavaExec task in Gradle. Right now I'm doing something like:

```
task foo(type: JavaExec) {
  if (project.hasProperty('prop1')) {
    args += ["--prop1"]
  }

  if (project.hasProperty('foo2')) {
    args += ["--foo3"]
  }

  ...
  if (project.hasProperty('flagn')) {
    args += ["--flagn"]
  }
}
```

And then when I execute this I do something like `./gradlew :foo -Pprop1 -Pfoo2 ... -Pflagn`. This works but is really tedious since I need to literally pass the same string arguments from Gradle to JVM. Is there an easier way - like automatically pass all the unparsed arguments or something simpler?

Comment: Do all properties have a common prefix/structure like in your example ?

Comment: @ToYonos: Not really - I probably should edit my post to reflect that. :)

Comment: *automatically pass all the unparsed arguments* : what is for your program a parsed argument ? A used one, a read one or just all properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the project properties from the command line via the [`StartParameter`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html) object.

So, for your example, you could use:

```
task foo(type: JavaExec) {
    args gradle.startParameter.projectProperties.keySet().collect { "--$it" }
}
```

However, this will add any command line project property to the `JavaExec` args. Maybe you could think about filtering for properties with a specific prefix.